# Differences between overloading operators c++

Tags: c++

which are the differences between those 3 implementations?

```
Box Box::operator+(const Box& b)
            {
                Box box;
                box.length = length + b.length;
                box.breadth = breadth + b.breadth;
                box.height = height + b.height;
                return box;
            }
```

or:

```
Box Box::operator+(const Box& b)
    {
        Box box;
        box.length = box.length + b.length;
        box.breadth = box.breadth + b.breadth;
        box.height = box.height + b.height;
        return box;
    }
```

or:

```
 Box Box::operator+(const Box& b)
    {
        Box box;
        box.length = this->length + b.length;
        box.breadth = this->breadth + b.breadth;
        box.height = this->height + b.height;
        return box;
    }
```

I noticed that with the second implementation, results are different wrt the other two implementations.
In the first case i suppose that this-> is implicit.
In the third case this is always the object who call that function, but the second case is equal to the others?

Many thanks!

Would be another possible solution to use:

```
example example::operator+(const example& obj2)
{
    example tmp_obj = *this;
    tmp_obj.a = tmp_obj.a + obj2.a;
    tmp_obj.b = tmp_obj.b + obj2.b;
    return tmp_obj;
}
```

Comment: No, because `this` becoms a `box` in 2nd

Comment: @appleapple what? in the second a new Box object is used and never anything from this. the second approach ignores everything what the `this` object has.

Comment: You may also want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4421706/operator-overloading)

Comment: @Hayt Yes, i just talk about the literal change (and which of course change the behavior), maybe I better delete that comment?

Answer (score 4):

### Method 1

For implementation one, you are doing the method that I would personally recommend. You are adding the current object's properties with `b`'s properties.

### Method 2

Method B is just plain wrong:

```
Box operator+(const Box& b)
    {
        Box box;
        box.length = box.length + b.length;
        box.breadth = box.breadth + b.breadth;
        box.height = box.height + b.height;
        return box;
    }
```

`box` is not initialized, and it **definitely** is not the current object, so the values that you are adding won't make sense, since you are adding the default constructed values for the `box` object, not the current object instance's value. In fact, to give you a better idea of why Method 2 is wrong, it is the equivalent of:

```
Box operator+(const Box& b)
    {
        Box box;
        box.length += b.length;
        box.breadth += b.breadth;
        box.height += b.height;
        return box;
    }
```

### Method 3

Method 3 is just an explicit way of doing method 1, with `this->` meaning "refer to the current object". As you said, `this->` is implied in method 1.

```
Box operator+(const Box& b)
            {
                Box box;
                box.length = length + b.length; //length == this->length
                box.breadth = breadth + b.breadth; //breadth == this->breadth
                box.height = height + b.height; //height == this->height
                return box;
            }
```

Comment: I would actual recommend they implement `operator+` with `operator+=` like `inline X operator+(X lhs, const X& rhs){ lhs += rhs; return lhs; }`so the addition code only has to sit in one place.

Comment: Good point, but in the OP's case of Method 2, that is just wrong

Comment: No doubt about that.

Comment: @juanchopanza Ah that it would.  Then I guess it would be better to make a copy in the function body and hope NRVO kicks in.

Comment: Would be another good solution using:                                                 `example example::operator+(const example& obj2)
{
    example tmp_obj = *this;
    tmp_obj.a = tmp_obj.a + obj2.a;
    tmp_obj.b = tmp_obj.b + obj2.b;
    return tmp_obj;
}`

Comment: Operator `+=` would be useful there @rollotommasi

Comment: Total aside but if you implement `operator+` you almost certainly want it to be a `const` method. Otherwise you should think about implementing `+=` or whether the function really conforms to `+`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason the second one is different is because you are referencing the newly created `Box` in the second one with `box.length`, `box.breadth`, and `box.height` instead of the one preceding the function. Instead of taking in the values of the one preceding the `+`, it will be taking in the values of the newly constructed `Box`.

Answer (score 1):

1) and 3) are essentially the same thing: the use of `this->` makes sense only if you have to distinguish between members and local variables of same name - definitively not the case here.

2) is just plainly wrong: it defines the uninitialized local `box` in term of itself. If Box has a default constructor the result is well defined (but it is not the arithmetic sum of `*this` and `b`).  If it doesn't, the result is essentially undefined (and hence compiler, optimization and running dependent)

Note that, in any case, the proper signature should be

```
Box operator+(const Box& b) const
```

Otherwise you won't be able to sum with temporaries (it happens withing long expressions)

Considering the symmetric nature of +, the best implementation should probably be

```
friend Box operator+(const Box& a, const Box& b)
{
    Box c;
    c.length = a.length + b.length;
    c.breadth = a.breadth + b.breadth;
    c.height = a.height + b.height;
    return c;
}
```

since it treats both arguments at same level.